# Can I have different breakpoints based on individual element in a responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am creating a responsive design for my site and I have read quite a bit on media queries and breakpoints. I understand that there is no set breakpoints since there are so many screens now-a-days and we need to choose the best that suits our layout. **But what I am not sure is if its okay to have different breakpoints for each element styled separately or is it better to group all the css to a common breakpoint that I use in my entire site.** Here is an example to explain what I mean by this:

Right now I do something like this:

Method 1:

```
 .search_bar { 
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
 }
  /* Media Queries for Search Bar */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .search_bar { 
        width: 40%;
    }
 }    
 @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .search_bar { 
        width: 50%;
    }   
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .search_bar { 
        width: 100%;
    }   
 }

 .side_bar_wrap {
    width: 300px;
 }
 /* Media Queries for Side Bar */
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
     .side_bar_wrap {
        width: 250px;
     }      
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .side_bar_wrap {
        width: 150px;
     }  
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
     .side_bar_wrap {
        display:none;
     }  
 }

 etc..etc..
```

If you noticed above, I do not have a set number of breakpoints for my entire template. I defined different breakpoints for each element based on how that individual elements behave in different screen sizes. This gives me an accurate way to align individual elements rather than defining all the elements in a common breakpoints. What I dont know is if the above method is recommended (or okay to use) or should I not do it like that? Do I need to change the above into something like this where I create common breakpoints for my entire website and add the styles grouped together into one of these common breakpoints?  Something like:

Method 2:

```
.search_bar { 
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}
.side_bar_wrap {
    width: 300px;
}

/* Common Breakpoints to my entire site */
 /* Media Queries for all elements are grouped into one of these */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
     .side_bar_wrap {
        width: 250px;
     }  
    .search_bar { 
        width: 40%;
    }        
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
     .side_bar_wrap {
        width: 150px;
     }  
     .search_bar { 
        width: 50%;
    }
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
     .side_bar_wrap {
        display:none;
     }  
     .search_bar { 
        width: 100%;
    }
 }
```

Is my first method a valid practice or I shouldn't be doing it like that? Can someone advise me if I am doing it right or wrong plz?

Comment: You *might* get better response at codereview.stackexchange.com (read their faq though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for best practice and solutions for questions like that are often based primarily on opinions. I'll try to give an objective answer, though.

In my opinion the most maintainable variant would be to go with method 2, i.e. keep media selectors to minimum:

- It easily allows to split CSS for different media devices to separate files.
- You have better outlook at what needs to be customized across different layouts: instead of scattering it, you keep it in one place.
- It makes CSS output code smaller, implying negligibly faster loading times.

Cons are that you scatter semantically coupled definitions, i.e. in this example rules for `#menu` get scattered all over the place:

```
#menu { base rules ... }
other base selectors and rules ...

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { #menu { custom rules 1 } }
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) { #menu { custom rules 2 } }
```

One solution to that would be giving up on trying to define base rules and define **everything** that needs to be customized in media selectors. That's not very good approach since you easily break *Don't Repeat Yourself* principle. Another, better approach would be to introduce base containers, like `#menu-container` which has constant base rules, and then `#menu` "implementation" which has rules defined exclusively in `@media` selectors.
Anyway, the point is not to mix base rules with device-specific rules, since it creates confusion when reading and modifying the code. (An exception to that are rules that define default layout on all devices; I'd keep these near device-specific rules.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @rr- Can I ask, is my method 1 logically wrong or is there a no right / wrong way? I understand now on the pros and cons of method 2 but in my first method, the pros I can see are that the media queries are semantically coupled with the elements (which I find is easier to maintain) and it gives more accurate alignment for each elements. But cons are it adds additional media queries and there will be too many various breakpoints when you look at the whole css. So will this cause any other effects on the browser other than slow loading speed that can be negligible?

Comment: Not really, it won't cause any problems. Your argument for method 1 is correct and I think it's true that there is no right / wrong way. It all depends on the scale of your project: the bigger the project, the more method 2 will make it easy on you to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your view @rr-. Your advise really helped. I will take take your suggestion on board and will review my code keeping future maintenance in mind. Thanks again.